# Share modules throw apps

Tags: symfony1, structure

Hi I am wondering if it's possible to share modules throw apps. 
In my project I have 3 applications and I am using the same module in each of them!

Making a plugin would be perfect, but my shared module is overwriting one of external plugin that I use. Do you have any idea of how I could do?

Maybe ordering module autoload... I don't have a clue!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put it in a plugin.

The order of plugins in your ProjectConfiguration determines the order they are loaded in. If you need to override another plugin, make sure yours is loaded after that.